# why are colors mixed up in CentOS 7 terminal?

Tags: bash, centos, terminal, colors, gnome-terminal

I have CentOS 7 running as a guest OS inside a VirtualBox host.  I opened a terminal to write some commands, but the colors are all messed up as shown in the following print screen:

[image]

It looks like text is highlighted, but the light blue against white background makes it nearly impossible to read.

**How can I restore the black text on white background so that I can read the terminal?**

White text on black background would be equally good.  I just need high contrast between text and background to be able to read.

Comment: Type this: `reset`.

Comment: @Cyrus Thank you.  However, typing `reset` had no effect.

Comment: Try this: `\ls -al`.

Comment: @Cyrus Thank you again. `\ls -l` makes the resulting text black on white background.  But then typing `ls -al` again results in the same light blue shown in the printscreen in my OP.  So `\ls -l` is a temporary patch.

Comment: Try this to see the problem: `alias ls`. With a leading \ you can disable the alias for this command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to last line of your `~/.bashrc`:

```
unalias ls
```

and type

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: Thank you and +1 for solving the problem in a timely manner.

Comment: or a solution for all users: `mv /etc/profile.d/colorls.sh /root`

Comment: I have what seems to be a downstream problem that seems to stem from these changes.  Are you willing to look at it?  Here is the link: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212493/bash-unalias-ls-not-found

Comment: I would prefer glenn's approach.