# -bash: unalias: ls: not found

Tags: bash, alias

I am trying to install tomcat 8 on centos 7.  I am using the terminal as root.  When I type in `source ~/.bashrc`, the terminal gives back the following error: `-bash: unalias: ls: not found`.

**How can I resolve this error so that the `source ~/.bashrc` command can succeed?**

Note that I recently added the line `unalias ls` as the last line of `~/.bashrc` as per [@Cyrus' solution to this other problem related to color aliasing in the same CentOS installation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/212234/why-are-colors-mixed-up-in-centos-7-terminal).

Comment: I got this error because I was running a file with a `unalias foo` line twice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't reproduce this but I assume the problem is because you have already unaliased `ls` once, so you can't unalias it again. However, I'm also pretty sure that the `source` command worked perfectly. Did you check? Chances are that it was sourced correctly and you can just ignore the error message.

More to the point, why are you running `source ~/.bashrc`? That file should be read when you start a new interactive non-login shell anyway. If it's to reload it because you made a change, then you're fine, your change was loaded. Ignore the error.

Answer (score 10):

You should only attempt to unalias if it is actually an alias: Change

```
unalias ls
```

to

```
[[ $(type -t ls) == "alias" ]] && unalias ls
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider putting `unalias ls 2>/dev/null` into your `~/.bashrc` instead - that way it won't display the error message that you're seeing even if `ls` had already been un-aliased.

Consider, also, not logging into a root shell - if you don't understand what this error is telling you, I'd submit that logging into a root shell isn't a very good idea.  With a regular user account, it's very difficult to make a mistake that breaks the system, and even more difficult to break it in a way that isn't fixed by rebooting.  With a root shell, breaking a system is very easy.

Comment: I prefer glenn's approach to only unalias ls if its an alias instead of just hiding an error.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant, to play devil's advocate, maybe you shouldn't.  They're functionally equivalent except that 1) the return values differ (0 for glenn's approach, 1 for mine), and 2) my approach is about 25x faster when timed in a tight loop.  If 1) bothers you, just use `unalias ls 2>/dev/null; true` instead to fix up the return code.

Answer (score 1):

```
[ -t 0 ] && unalias ls
```

This doesn't directly test whether `ls` is actually aliased, rather it tests for whether you are in a terminal, which is a little simpler especially if there is more code in your `~/.bashrc` that you want treated the same:

```
if [ -t 0 ]; then
  unalias ls
  # ... any other terminal-only actions
fi
```